# How should I act if I find an answer to a question that I've posted

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

More specifically what is the preferred course of action if I find my answer in another question that might have a title that doesn't really describe my question or is poorly written but that does have an accepted answer that also answers my question?

Answer (score 3):

You should do the following things:

1. If necessary edit the other question to improve it so that it is clear.
2. Vote (or flag) your question for closure as a duplicate if it really is a duplicate. Note that while having an answer that helps you is an **indication** that the questions are duplicates, it's not necessarily enough to make the questions duplicate **on it's own**.

Leave your question on the site as it provides another set of search terms for people looking for similar problems.

Comment: Thanks, if I may, what do you think I should do in this case?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354527/what-exactly-is-ie5-quirks-in-ie-10-developer-tools

Comment: @DanielFigueroa In this case I think your question is a duplicate of the earlier one. I'm not sure that the other question is particularly unclear. It's just one of these times where you're searching for the same thing using different search terms.